# How to attach datatables options when using ui router

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am using angular-datatables to format my tables. I am also using ui-routing to handle routing.

It is possible to define the formatting of the dataTable by attaching a couple of objects to $scope in the controler (http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withOptions), like:

```
angular.module('datatablesSampleApp', ['datatables']).controller('withOptionsCtrl', function($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder) {
     $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
        .withDisplayLength(2)
        .withDOM('pitrfl');
    $scope.dtColumnDefs = [
        DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).notSortable(),
        DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1).notVisible(),
        DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(2)
    ];
});
```

The dataTable is rendered like:

```
<table datatable="ng" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
```

My route  is defineded as:

```
.state('unclassified', {
    url: "/unclassified",
    templateUrl: "/app/documentsUnclassified/documentsunclassified.html",
    controller: 'documentUnclassifiedCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'documentsUnclassified'
}
```

My question is how I can do this in the most efficient way since I don't have access to $scope in the controller when I am using ui router.

Comment: FYI: You don't have access to $scope because you're using the controllerAs syntax, that's got nothing to do with ui-router specificly. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `controllerAs` syntax, you need to use the variable `documentsUnclassified` you set in your router in the HTML:

```
<table datatable="ng" 
    dt-options="documentsUnclassified.dtOptions" 
    dt-column-defs="documentsUnclassified.dtColumnDefs" 
    class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
</table>
```